# Cannot copy files from/to a shared directory in a remote windows desktop from linux using ssh

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, remote-access, shared-folders

I have setup a passwordless login from my Linux System to a Windows System through the ssh key pair. Now, I want to copy a file from a shared directory in the Windows System to another Directory also in the Windows System using ssh from my Linux. i.e I want to do something like

```
ssh -i path/to/my/private_key user@system copy shared_directory/file target
```

But, when i try this, I get an `Access Denied` error. But when i try to do the same copy process using my password instead of my private key, I can do it without any problem. Also, I can copy files from/to 'non-shared' folders without any problem. But, for a certain task, I dont want to use my password or do a scp from Linux to Windows.

I can't understand the source of the problem or find a workaround. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!